# javascript looping through li attributes and changing values per item

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I want to loop through a bunch of `<li>` elements and update the value held in it, and show this on the document.

The reason i'm doing this is because I want to sort a list of elements in an order. I do this using Sortable in JQuery.

```
<li> 1 </li>
<li> 2 </li>
<li> 3 </li>
<li> 4 </li>
<li> 5 </li>
```

the order may become:

```
    <li> 3 </li>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 4 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 5 </li>
```

Then clicking a button i would like my JS function to change the value of the li items back to 1,2,3,4,5. Its worth noting i am not looking for a solution to revert back to how the list was before.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, ... always? In that case you could go through the items (each method) and set their index accordingly. No need to worry about the old values, just override. :)

Comment: yeah thats what im trying to do, loop through and override with what i expect. what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: I guess something along $elems.each(function(index) {this.html(index)}); would do the trick. My jQuery-fu is in a bit bad form atm but hopefully you can derive the solution based on that. :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work (as of jQuery 1.4):

```
$('.your_list li').text(function (index) {
    return index + 1;
});
```

Comment: Clever. Nice to see you can pass a func directly to "text" method. Cool solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would rather reorder the list items than their contents.  This way, you don't lose any of the `li`'s attributes/classes/...  And you can keep the DOM's elements intact, only change the order of some `ul`'s children.

I found a nice little snippet do do it:

http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

The only thing you still need to do is remember the initial order

```
function mysortA( a, b ) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;    
}
function mysortB( a, b ) {
  return   a.originalindex < b.originalindex ? -1 
         : a.originalindex > b.originalindex ?  1 
         : 0;
}
```

You have to initialize:

```
var ul = $('ul');
var listitems = ul.children('li').get();

// remember original index
listitems.each( function(index, li){ li.originalindex=index; } );
```

Then you can sort one way:

```
// sort them using your sort function
listitems.sort( mysort )
// rebuild the list container
listitems.each( function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

And sort back:

```
var ul=$('ul');
ul.children('li').get().sort(mysortB).each(function(i,li){ ul.append(li); });
```

Note: untested - grab the idea.